# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/consume

Tags: app-store-connect, ios8, xcode6gm, developer-payload

I am facing a problem while validating my app using XCode GM.
Is this warning has something to do with code change or this is simply an Apple validation Script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found a solution for that

Comment: There is no solution found for this issue. I submitted to the App with this warning and got it approved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also submitted the app with that warning and my app also got approved. Come to my issue that warning is causing some third party library so i removed that.

Comment: Could you please name that library.. beacuse I am not sure of the warning cause.